# NOTICE Array to string conversion on line number ... [multidimensional array]

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have this simple array defined:

```
1: <?php
2: $_ext = array(
3:  array('doc', 'docx'),
4:  array('xls', 'xlsx'),
5:  array('ppt', 'pptx'),
6:  array('php'),
    array('html'),
    array('pdf'),
    array('js').
    array('java'),
    array('zip', 'rar')
  );
```

When I run it i get the following error

NOTICE Array to string conversion on line number 3

NOTICE Array to string conversion on line number 3

I even tested this on the webpage http://phptester.net/ and I got the same error. I don't know which php version my host is using but probably the newest.

I read this w3schools article (https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp) about multidimensional arrays and I don't really know what I am doing wrong.

Thank you in advance for your help. :)

Comment: The code you give, when including [**delx's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45335144/3536236) works fine for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the line `array('js').`. There's a typo: Try replacing the point with a comma.

Comment: Yes, this solved the error. Will mark this question as the right one as soon as it allows me to. I still don't understand why it gives the error on line 3 when the error somewhere else. @Martin

Comment: Because that's the line it started adding the array elements on.